# validate input's float format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate an input value, 0~99.99, float type, and only two digit after the decimal point, like

valid example :

```
 0
 1
 .1
 .12
 12.12
```

invalid example :

```
 (empty)
 100
 123.1
 .123
 12.123
```

So I create this regexp

```
var isValid = new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$/).test(parseFloat($('#myText').val()));
```

any other way to check ? make code easier and simpler.

Comment: What about 023.1? Should it be considered valid? It would make sense to admit leading zeros.

Comment: yes, ur suggestion is necessary. I think 023 means 23 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the regex:

```
^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^\.\d{1,2}$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dJ7dW3)

The regex is in two parts:

`^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` This will accept numbers with 2 digits, an possible decimals with up to two decimal digits.

`^` matches the beginning of the line,

`\d{1,2}` matches any number at least 1 time and at most 2 times.

`(?: ... )` is a non capture group (this makes the regex a little more efficient by not having to keep the captured group)

`?` near the end indicates 0 or 1 times,

`$` indicate the end of line (thus ensuring there are no more numbers).

The second part `^\.\d{1,2}$` accepts decimals where the first digit can be absent, as such, `.1` will pass.

The first and second part are linked with an `|` (OR operator) which means that if a match fails for the first part, the engine will try with the second part before calling it a no-match

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. It's not more complicated than the first answer, you'll notice their regex changed to be very much like mine ;)

Comment: Yep, initially I looked at Kevin's regex and thought it looked about right so my answer focused on other things, but his comment (under my answer) prompted me to look a bit more closely. +1 for getting the regex right first.

Comment: I can try other input text in regex101 page except (empty). Basically it's really helpful. thx !

Comment: @Kevin Empty is there, it's just an empty line ;)

Comment: @Kevin No problem, I hadn't thought that it could be difficult for you to understand, since your own regex was pretty good, and missing only a little part. ^^;

Answer (score 2):

> *" make code easier and simpler."*

OK. Here you go:

```
var isValid = /^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$|^\.\d\d?$/.test($('#myText').val());
```

You don't need to use `new RegExp()` when you already have a regex literal.

Your regex didn't accept a `.` as the first character.

And if you pass the result of `parseFloat()` to `.test()` you are not validating what the user actually entered because `parseFloat()` ignores leading spaces and trailing non numeric data. So your code would accept, e.g., `"    12abc"` as valid. If you do actually wish to ignore leading or trailing spaces you can cater for that in your regex.

Comment: sounds good. I feel better now. how about the inner regexp script ?

Comment: Am I missing something? Since when did we start defining the data types of our variables in JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks @MicahHenning - Obviously I just copied that from the question without thinking about it. Fixed.

Comment: I was seriously starting to question whether a new version of ECMAScript was released hahaha

Comment: _"how about the inner regexp script"_ - I just looked at it more closely and realised it wasn't accepting input like `".12"` - answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that also accepts leading and trailing zeros: http://regex101.com/r/hV1uD8

```
/^(?:0*\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?$|^(?:0*\.)(?:\d{1,2}0*)$/
```

Valid examples:

```
0 
1 
.1 
.12
12.12
23.1
023.1
12.1200
012.120
1.
1.010
```

Invalid:

```
100
123.1 
.123
12.123
12.1201
```

Or you could use `parseFloat` to take care of leading and trailing zeros and then the regular expression suggested in the other answer:

```
var isValid = /^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$|^\.\d{1,2}$/.test(parseFloat($('#myText').val()));
```

but this would be less efficient because you would parse the same expression twice.

Comment: I think use parseFloat could make code trivial. but when I parseFloat('023') I got '19'. it seems not what I want !

Comment: So maybe I should trim('0') before regexp test.